# D3D11 Resource method Release() won't deallocate memory

Tags: c++, directx, buffer, release, direct3d

So, in tree(which process frustum culling), I call

```
// in some_header.h
#define SAFE_RELEASE(x) { if ((x)) { (x)->Release(); } (x) = nullptr; }

// in ClearGeometry() inside model.cpp
SAFE_RELEASE(m_pVertexBuffer);
```

(Actually, I call it in model method, which calls from the tree.)

This command executs 100%. I have debugged it.

Buffer creation:

```
// inside loader.cpp

        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
        ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
        bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(CVertex)* pMesh->m_nVertices;
        bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
        bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
        ZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
        InitData.pSysMem = pVertices;

        if (pMesh->m_pVertexBuffer)
        {
            printf("debugger don't stopped here\n");
        }

        V_RETURN(pD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &InitData, &pMesh->m_pVertexBuffer));
```

Why I release buffer in realtime?

Count of objects in scene is very big, and I have to unload and download part of them in realtime(because of RAM and GPU memory not rubber).

And memory doesn't deallocates! Used GPU memory and RAM only grows!

What happens? Why memory doesn't deallocates? So strange problem...
Help!

**UPD**

I tried this:

```
while (m_pVertexBuffer->Release())
{}
```

The same results...

Comment: You should paste the code to delete your buffers.

Comment: What code? I paste it in the first 4 lines. And in the end(UPD).

Comment: Why did you call it immediately after the macro definition? you should call it after you create the buffer and don't want to use the buffer any more. why you put it in a while loop?

Comment: You ask, how API functions work? ok... Release returns count of references. If count != 0, Release() decreases it. If inside resource  count == 0, resource will release.

Comment: No, I mean you should paste the code where you call SAFE_RELEASE()

Comment: Ok, I understand you. Look at the modified version.

Comment: Don't just paste a comment said where you call it, put the real code please.

Comment: Meamory leak might be caused by many reasons, do you have any other CreateXXX functions in you app?

Comment: there is no memory leak...

Comment: And memory doesn't deallocates! Used GPU memory and RAM only grows! isn't this a memory leak?

Comment: none of the codes you post now can help to solve your question, I ask you to paste the code on how you call you macro, but you only paste one line.

Comment: If you are sure the macro was called, but the memory was still grow, you must allocate memory somewhere else.

Comment: SAFE_RELEASE(m_pVertexBuffer); this is the call!!! if you don't know graphics api, please, don't answer.

Comment: We need to check where you call release for a simple reason, your resource will not released immediately,gpu resource gets freed when: reference count is 0, resource is not bound anywhere in the pipeline, gpu is flushed (which will normally happen at least when you call present).

Comment: I call it somewhere "I don't know where". Because of it calls from another thread. Okok, I tried another solution: put releasing somewhere near the start of frame. Result is the same.

Comment: **Close FRAPS.** It messes with the reference counter. --- Also use a smart pointer. Don't see if you can get one working properly yourself.